# MotionLayout: how to animate margin

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'm using `MotionLayout` to animate the resizing of a view from full screen to a smaller dimension that has particular margins (as per following).  It mostly works fine but the margins shown are 0 until the very end of animation after which they're applied immediately.  Is there any way to animate those as well?

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/localVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/localVideoView"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"/>
</ConstraintSet>
```

I've tried using `KeyFrameSet` to create intermediate point with different margin values but that had no effect.

For example

```
    <KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            app:framePosition="50"
            app:target="@id/localVideoView">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="layoutMarginBottom"
                motion:customDimension="92dp" />
        </KeyAttribute>
    </KeyFrameSet>
```

**UPDATE**

So, looks like issue is related to fact that I'm using `SurfaceView`...if I try with an `ImageView` for example the margin does change gradually.

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly, but it works for me using MotionLayout 2.0.0 Alpha 3. Try defining the margin in a Layout Tag (ConstraintSet > Constraint > Layout) through `motion:layout_margin...`.

Comment: @jossiwolf you're seeing the margin gradually change?  I'm also using Alpha 3 here btw.  I tried using `motion:` for those attributes but margin didn't change at all in that case (even at end of animation)

Comment: @jossiwolf I might have misunderstood though what you suggested...could you include what you have in an answer and I'll try that?

Comment: Added an update...looks like issue is related to fact that I'm using `SurfaceView`

Comment: Well, that may be the reason - although I'm not exactly sure why :(

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceView does not allow proper transformation, If you need transformation you should use TextureView.